# Why can`t I redefine function's prototype from within itself

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am trying to implement a way to achieve inheritance in JavaScript. First I define the base class, as follows:

```
function Person(name){
    name = name + "!"; //I want to reuse this code for initialization

    this.getName = function(){
        return name;
    };

    this.setName = function(_name){
        name = _name;
    };
};
```

Then I define the sub class. Happens that I need a way to call the base class constructor. Ideally I would call it from within `VipPerson` constructor, when I still have a reference for `name` param. But if I do it from that point it simply does not work and if I try to access `getName` from base class I get an error that `VipPerson has no getName method`.

```
function VipPerson(name, vipLevel){
    this.getVipLevel = function(){
        return vipLevel;
    };

    //the line below would not work!
    //VipPerson.prototype = new Person(name);
};

VipPerson.prototype = new Person(); //but this would. not ideal IMO
```

The drawback for me to set the prototype from outside the `VipPerson` is that I lose any reference to the parameter were passed.

Is there an elegant way to solve this? I would like to have this clean interface:

```
var foo = new Person("Foo");
console.log(foo.getName());

var bar = new VipPerson("Bar", 100);
console.log(bar.getName()); //error
console.log(bar.getVipLevel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this approach?

```
function VipPerson(name, vipLevel){
    this.__proto__ = new Person(name);

    this.getVipLevel = function(){
        return vipLevel;
    };
};
```

Comment: Notice that is this way you're not doing inheritance, like the question seems to asked: `var vp = new VipPerson("John"); alert(vp instanceof Person) // false`. In order to have the proper inheritance, you need to set the `prototype` correctly. See my answer for details.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @ZERO. Although youre answer implements inheritance, it can cause a very large bug. When you call the function "call" passing as argument the "this" you're replicating all the attributes of Person in VipPerson. Changing the prototype, will create the same attributes in the prototype.

Comment: It's not a bug, that's what the inheritance does. If `Person` have a method `foo` I want that as well in `VipPerson`. The fact that the constructor extend dynamically the object is not related to my proposal or inheritance, but to the original code, that I explicitly said it shouldn't be done. It's preferable use the `prototype` to define methods, however you can't really have "privates" in that case (and usually, it's fine in JS). Your new edit with `__proto__` is not standard, and can't be used cross browsing.

Answer (score 2):

```
function VipPerson(name, vipLevel){
    Person.call(this, name);

    this.getVipLevel = function(){
        return vipLevel;
    };
};

VipPerson.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create/

However, I would avoid create closures just to make "privates" variables, unless there are specific security issues. JavaScript is a dynamic language with OOP prototype based, shouldn't be used like a class-based language with privates members.

I suggest to you to reading articles like that one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

It sort-of works when you set the prototype from inside the constructor, but it doesn't do what you really want.  Because the setting of the prototype object is made until you're already running the constructor, the first newly created object (`this`) in thefirst call to the  "VipPerson" constructor will not be "wired up" properly.

However, if you call the constructor *again*, you'll note that the prototype is there and that ".getName()" works.

Note that unless you want all your "Person" objects to share the same name, it's not going to work either way. "Person" should be set up such that "setName()" updates `this.name` and not a variable in the closure. There'll only be one "Person" instance for *all* the "VipPerson" instances — that being the instantiated prototype object.

Comment: Hey @Pointy, can you take a look at @Geraldo Ferraz answer? By using `call` method I was able to have different Person for each VipPerson... what do you think?

Comment: Well, you don't really have a separate "Person" object, you just use the "Person" constructor function to populate properties on the newly-constructed "VipPerson".  Thus, there really is no separate prototype object with that approach. If it works for you however there's nothing really wrong with it. *edit* - I would recommend *not* setting the prototype property; the answer from ZERO is better.